# Какую книгу лучше выбрать для изучение структур данных в Java?

Tags: java

*Роберт Седжвик* **"Алгоритмы на Java"** или *Роберт Лафоре* **"Структуры данных и алгоритмы в Java"**

Comment: Выбирайте любую и больше практикуйтесь. Не прогадаете.

Comment: Дональд Кнут - Искусство программирования

Comment: Я бы взял любую, но Лафоре даже просто должен быть в моей библиотеке - настолько хорош.